# Downloading existing paypal payments with rest api

Tags: ruby, paypal

I need to download all existing payment information from a paypal account to do some analysis on it, so I set up paypal's ruby rest sdk, which involved creating a new application with its own API keys and whatnot. I can make a successful request with the following:

```
payment_history = Payment.all( :count => 10 )
```

However,

```
payment_history.payments
```

Is empty.

I'm not sure if this application can only access payments created with it? Can I not get pre-existing payments with the rest api? I would prefer to use ruby, if that's possible, as I would like to keep this all within the simple script I have to analyze similar stripe payments.

Some guidance would be extremely appreciated, as paypal's labrinth of documentation and overlapping APIs have me pretty confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to query only those payments that are made or created with Rest API not the Classic APIs. You can use the Classic Ruby SDKs for the appropriate product to get the Transaction details of the classic APIs

Comment: I use PayPal buttons on [my site](http://webplatformdaily.org) to perform payments. Is it possible to retrieve a history of those payments via the PayPal REST API or do I have to manually download the history (as a CSV file) from the PayPal site?

Comment: Does this "only able to query only those payments that are made or created with Rest API " still hold ?