# REST api list payment returns no results

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm developing a windows desktop application to automatically download PayPal transactions and save them in csv files.

I'm using the REST Api SDK for .NET.
When I use the Payment.List function to list payment resources in the sandbox it works like a charm.
For testing I used the credientials from the REST Api Documantation:
https://developer.PayPal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token

I then added the application to my PayPal account to get my own clientId and clientSecret.
But when I use those credientials to call Payment.List the resulting PaymentHistory object is always empty (count = 0, payments = null) regardless of how I filter via the containerDictionary object.
This holds true for my sandbox credientials and my live credientials.
When I look at account on PayPal website I can see my incoming and outgoing payments.

Do I have to take further steps to successfully access my PayPal account with the REST Api?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal REST API "List Payments" returns no entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801436/paypal-rest-api-list-payments-returns-no-entries)

Answer (score 0):

I found related question with Paypal Ruby SDK [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138224/downloading-existing-paypal-payments-with-rest-api). It looks like you can only get Payments created using REST API, via get payments REST API.