# PayPal REST API "List Payments" returns no entries

Tags: rest, curl, paypal

I'm trying to use PayPal REST API to get a list of payments. Typically these payments will have been made via eBay.

When I try the sandbox I can get a token, and then get a list of payments as expected. But when I switch to live the list is always empty.

For example, using curl:

```
curl https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
 -u "ASnXAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPP7sBaB:EGWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXs-NU" \
 -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

<response>
{"scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault /credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* openid","access_token":"dzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHJs-XXXXXA","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-1JCXXXXXXXXXXX08","expires_in":28800}
```

Then I take the token from the response body and call the payments list resource:

```
 curl -v -X GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer dzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHJs-XXXXXA"

<response>
{"count":0}
```

There are actually payments in the account, so am I doing something wrong? I've not managed to google up any useful answers. I saw a suggestion on one post that maybe only payments made via the REST API are returned by the REST API? If that is the case (then the rest API would be of limited used) then is there another way to get a list of payments received? Again, I've had no luck in finding one in the paypal docs or google so far.

Thanks for any advice or help.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: I concluded that only payments made through the Rest API are accessible by the Rest API. I've not tried any of the non-rest (classic) APIs yet as I was hoping that PayPal would improve on the rest ones.

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this issue. Strangely, It seems that the PayPal REST API only returns results for payments made *through* the REST API. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139747

Classic API will remain the way to do this until the REST API is improved.

Comment: Over 3 years later, still not implemented. Requests for it keep being shuffled to a new issue; latest iteration is at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/9