# Which paypal api to just fetch all transactions

Tags: ruby, paypal

Very confused by the crowd of paypal-APIs, I wonder if I just can fetch the transactions (in and out) somehow, just like I would it export to csv via webinterface.

Here I am:

- [REST-API](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) seems not working for "non-rest-transactions" `Payment.all.size == 0`  [paypal-rest-api-list-payments-returns-no-entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801436/paypal-rest-api-list-payments-returns-no-entries)
- Merchant-API does not allow detailed info for specific transactions. 
  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/ says:

  > Note The details for some kinds of transactions cannot be retrieved
  >   with GetTransactionDetails. You cannot obtain details of bank transfer
  >   withdrawals, for example.

  I recieved a view transactions via transactionSearch. Took the transactionId from one of the transactions.

  ```
  api.get_transaction_details(:transaction_id => transaction_id>)
  => #<PayPal::SDK::Merchant::DataTypes::GetTransactionDetailsResponseType:0x007fd3c0f1f8d8 
  @Ack="Failure", 
  @Errors=[#<PayPal::SDK::Merchant::DataTypes::ErrorType:0x007fd3c0f379d8 
    @ShortMessage="Invalid transaction type", 
    @LongMessage="You can not get the details for this type of transaction", 
    @ErrorCode="10004", 
    @SeverityCode="Error">]
  ```
- Adaptive-API (`PaymentDetails` with transactionID) throws an "internal error 520002" with no details. (And I found no specification if it could fetch all transactions)

Ok, it's Paypal. But there must be a simple solution they forgot to mention. (?!) Or what did I miss?

Thanks and regards, Phil

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second bullet? This is a response from PayPal's GetTransactionDetails API? With what inputs?TransactionSearch/GetTransactionDetails to be the reliable way to do this; not limited to Express Checkout transactions. But these are limited to "original" transaction IDs. So if you do a transaction through the REST interface and try to GetTransactionDetails on the ID returned by that API it won't work. However the underlying transaction WILL be present in a TransactionSearch, with a different (underlying/original) ID.

Comment: Think of it as if the REST Payment APIs were built by another company (call it "NewPay") as a "new, better way to make PayPal transactions": you wouldn't expect the underlying PayPal code to be aware of NewPay's data around the transaction, or expect NewPay to be aware of non-NewPay PayPal transactions. Or well, maybe you would, and PayPal could have made a tighter integration, but they didn't.

Comment: Also: PayPal provides many ways to autogenerate transaction reports and fetch them; depending upon your use case you may want to consider one of those mechanisms rather than APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Elaborated the second bullet. (I just took the transactionId provided by transactionSearch). I will dig into your other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're seeing info that the merchant API won't provide details about transactions, but that's simply wrong.

You you can use [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain a list of transactions within a given time period, and then you can loop through those results and use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain the details for each individual transaction.

Comment: I did exactly that. Leading to the "You can not get the details for this type of transaction"-message. See edited question.

Comment: Did you maybe pull the transaction ID of a sub-transaction (e.g. a cross-currency conversion being done as part of a payment)? TS should still work, I think, but there might be gaps for odd cases. What is the transaction ID in question & the transaction search result describing this transaction? In particular, what is the transaction type?

Comment: If you use the REST API to create a payment, then you would need to use the REST API to pull details about that payment, too.  If you use the Classic API (or PayPal Standard) to process payments, then you could use the classic APIs I mentioned to obtain details.  This is one of the many reasons I've yet to use REST myself.  Classic provides a lot more features and doesn't have any limitations like REST does.

Comment: It seems I can not get the details of all our bank transfer withdrawals. Just as Paypal said at the dev-pages. See added link in op. I also noticed a "fee refunding" transaction, where no details ar available.