# PayPal Fetch All Client's Transactions

Tags: paypal, oauth, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to fetch all PayPal transactions. (after the client has authenticated with OAuth2)

I saw some answers about using NVP instead, like
[Which paypal api to just fetch all transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764751/which-paypal-api-to-just-fetch-all-transactions)

But this answer is from 4 years ago and this API was deprecated 2 years ago https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

The current REST endpoint only returns transactions that were created via the API, not all of the transactions.

Is there now a better way to do this? or do we have to resort to the old deprecated API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any fully fledged, documented API that makes this available using the OAuth2 authorization (in my experience, the OAuth2 interface is barely usable for anything).

I expect if you need full transaction details you'll need to go the SFTP reports route (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/sftp-reports/ and https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/PP_LRD_Gen_TransactionDetailReport.pdf). However I don't think those are available for non-merchant accounts, and it is definitely not OAuth2 protected: needs an SFTP user to be set up.