# Paypal: Transaction History with REST API / Nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal, transactions

### I would like to display all the inbound/outbound transactions a user made/received to display it in a simple html list.

I'm using the recommended node.js module https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs and I'm trying to use this code to get the transactions:

```
    // Get Transaction History
    paypal.payment.list({ 
        'count': 100,
        'sort_by':'create_time',
        'sort_order': 'asc',
        'start_time': '2008-03-06T11:00:00Z'
    }, function(error, payment_history){
        if(error){
            console.error('error', error);
            response.data.payment_history = {};
        } else {
            console.log('history', payment_history);
            response.data.payment_history = payment_history;
        }
        response.finish();
    });
```

but `payment_history` gives me `{ count: 0 }`. I'm pretty sure that I have transactions since 2008.

I'm not really sure what's the problem. The user is already logged in using the `access_token` and I can display user informations but I have no idea how to pull transaction informations.

Answer (score 1):

Look into https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#general-developer-questions for the answer to "Can I retrieve the history of transactions created using the Classic APIs using the REST API?".

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. Strangely, It seems that the PayPal REST API only returns results for payments made through the REST API. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139747

Classic API will remain the way to do this until the REST API is improved.