# Nodejs Paypal get the account history

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to get the account history of my account with nodejs and the paypal-rest-sdk but as response to the following code is just an empty object
{"count":0, "httpStatusCode":200}

```
/* Copyright 2015-2016 PayPal, Inc. */
"use strict";

var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

paypal.configure({
  'mode': 'live', //sandbox or live 
  'client_id': 'my id',
  'client_secret': 'my secret'
});

var listPayment = {
    'count': '1',
    'start_index': '1'
};

paypal.payment.list(listPayment, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("List Payments Response");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
    }
});
```

is this the right way or did i've done something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal: Transaction History with REST API / Nodejs SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150378/paypal-transaction-history-with-rest-api-nodejs-sdk)

Comment: Apparently, you can only query payments that are made or created with the Rest API, but not those created with the Classic APIs. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138224/downloading-existing-paypal-payments-with-rest-api/18139747#18139747

Comment: is there still no other way as with the ruby "hack"? So that cant be done with node js?

Comment: Sorry, no idea -- I haven't worked with this myself.