# List payment resources

Tags: api, rest, soap, paypal

I'm trying to use any of the PayPal APIs to receive a list of payments which have been made to a particular PayPal account. From reading the developer docs it seemed that the SOAP and NVP APIs are now less favoured (although still available) compared to the newer REST API. I had a preference to use REST over SOAP so tried to use the REST API to call [list payment resources](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources), however I always got back an empty list of payments despite there being payments in the both the sandbox and live accounts.

I subsequently read [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139747/343763) which claimed that payments will only show up in the REST API if they were made through that API i.e. payments made through other means such as eBay or through Paypal buttons don't appear in the REST API data. This seems pretty odd to me but I just wanted to get something working to prove a concept initially so I thought I'll try and use the SOAP API.

I then tried to register an app against the SOAP API, following the instructions at: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ This page contains a link to https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications which has returned a 502 every time I've tried it.

So my first foray in to the world of PayPal APIs has been very frustrating so far. I've tried [asking @AskPaypal](https://twitter.com/eddgrant/status/698080432152305664) on twitter but they've not been active since the 8th of Feb hence me now looking for answers here.

Most grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction here. Either to confirm if there *is* a way to obtain the data through the REST API or who I could poke to get the 502 fixed so I can sign up to get some SOAP API credentials.

Thanks!

Edd

Comment: Having the same problem. Why would the REST APIs not return payments that weren't made through them?

Answer (score 0):

REST APIs are isolated from classic API transaction data, so the answer as of now is no, you won't be able to fetch the transactions made from the classic APIs.

While in Classic APIs (SOAP/NVP) you may make use of `TransactionSearch` and `GetTransactionDetails` calls to fetch the records, APP registration is irrelevant for these APIs, the credentials are right in the PayPal account (API user name / password / signature): [Instructions on obtaining API credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/?mark=api%20credential)